# Optimization to write raw images

Tags: c++, image, optimization, memory, fwrite

I capture images from MIPI camera.
I have access to the **.raw** pointer. I want to save images in **.raw** as fast as possible.

The resolution of one image is **4224*3008**.

I cope with two difficulties. Below an example to explain my problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("file.raw", "wb");
  unsigned short* buffer = new unsigned short[3008*4224];

  for (int i=0 ; i<600 ; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0 ; j<3008*4224 ; j++ ){buffer[j] = i ;}

      fwrite (buffer , sizeof(unsigned short), 3008*4224, pFile);
  }

  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

This sample I wrote illustrates perfectly my issues.

I expect **.raw** with a size of **15.2GB**, and a time to write in .raw more or less constant.

1. I can write only **4.3GB**, then the code "skip" the function **fwrite(..)**. Anyone has already encounter this problem ?
2. The function is really, really slow. At the beginning, the average time is around 250ms to write one image, and after some iterations, this time is around 2200ms. Does someone has an idea ?

It is probably not the most efficient solution to write images in **.raw**, but I didn't other solutions. I tested to write with openCV in **.tif**, it is faster than **.raw** but I am pretty sure that it is because I have a problem in my code.
If someone has tips, it would be great !

I am working on jetson TX2 board, which runs L4T (linux for tegra).

The file system of my sd card is ext3/Ext4:

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1 ext4       28G   12G   15G  44% /
none           devtmpfs  3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     3,9G   21M  3,9G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     785M  124K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1      fuseblk    58G   18G   40G  32% /media/nvidia/Ubuntu
/dev/mmcblk2p1 ext4       15G  5,2G  8,7G  38% /media/nvidia/sdCard
tmpfs          tmpfs     785M     0  785M   0% /run/user/0
```

I use nvcc compiler. I use -03 as well as -use_fast_math.

Thank you !

Comment: Does your filesystem support files larger than 4gb? Your first writes are probably just filling a disk buffer, once the buffer is full it'll slow down to the speed of the disk. Do you have compiler optimisations enabled?

Comment: FAT32 filesystems cannot handle files larger than 4GB... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for answer.

Yes it does. Actually, I wrote the file on 80MB/s micro SD card, of 16GB. 
And yes, I have compiler optimization, with the flag -O3.

Comment: What operating system, filesystem, compiler and compiler options are you using? Maybe one aspect of your environment is 32-bit.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell
Thank you for your help. I am going to update my post to answer your question

Comment: I would try with commandline tools to see if they can write an 8GB file with something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/nvidia/sdCard/JUNK bs=8000000 count=1000`

Comment: @MarkSetchell the function doesn't work, only 1.2GB was wrote

Comment: Sorry actually 8GB was wrote, but in 20 min ...

Comment: Ok, so you aren't hitting a limitation inherent in the filesystem. I can only guess your compiler options don't include `--machine 64` (or whatever it is) or you haven't defined some `O_LARGEFILES` constant. Not familiar enough with Jetson.